# C++ template default argument based on next argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I need to do something like this:

```
template<class A=B, class B>
    A fn(B x) { return A(x); };

int main()
{
    int i = fn(5); // Error, no matching overload found
    double d = fn<double>(5);
};
```

Hence, a function template which deduces the types automatically from the function arguments, but the caller can change the first one if needed. Any way to do this?

Comment: Use a placeholder type (`void`?), then choose the right type with `std::conditional_t`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin because mrzacek wants fn<int> to be `int fn(B x)` and not `B fn(int x)`

Comment: @JerryCoffin does it call `int fn(int)` or the intended `int fn(double)`? (hint: it's obviously the first one)

Comment: @user253751: Ah, quite right.

Comment: The whole point is to be able to specify the FIRST template parameter manually in specific cases. The example above is very simplified version of what I actually have, where there are several template parameters deduced automatically and the first on is usually based on one of them, but may be not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `constexpr if` in such cases like:

```
struct NO_TYPE;

template<class RET_TYPE = NO_TYPE, class IN_TYPE>
    auto fn(IN_TYPE x)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< RET_TYPE, NO_TYPE> )
    {    
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        return IN_TYPE(x);
    }    
    else 
    {    
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
        return RET_TYPE(x);
    }    
}

int main()
{
    int i = fn(5); // Error, no matching overload found
    double d = fn<double>(5);
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `using A_ = std::conditional_t<std::is_same<A,NO_TYPE>::value, B, A>::type`?